# Bash Scripting with functions

Tags: bash, shell

What does this line of code mean

`[ -n "$local_var" ] && eval $1=\$local_var`

I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: What specific part of it is unclear? (If the answer is "everything", please start with [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%5B+-n+%22%24local_var%22+%5D+%26%26+eval+%241%3D%5C%24local_var), [what is eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash) and [what is -n](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109625/shell-scripting-z-and-n-options-with-if))

Comment: It's a particularly dangerous way to create a variable dynamically, but providing a better alternative would require more context about where this code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

`[ -n "$var" ]` evaluates to true (i.e. return exit status `0`) if the length of `$var` is non-zero. Also `cmd1 && cmd2` executes `cmd2` only if `cmd1` returns an exit status of zero. And `cmd1 && cmd2` executes `cmd2` only if `cmd1` returns a non-zero exit status. Perhaps an example can help illustrate what your code is doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                             

# $local_var has not been initialized so has length zero                                                                               
[ -n "$local_var" ] || echo '$local_var' has zero length                        
# Prints: $local_var has zero length                                            

var=foo                                                                         
local_var=bar                                                                   

[ -n "$local_var" ] && eval $var=\$local_var                                    
# Above line is equivalent to:                                                  
# [ -n "$local_var" ] && foo=$local_var                                         
echo "$var $foo $local_var"                                                     
# Prints: foo bar bar
```

Comment: it is `$var=\$local_var` and `$var='$'local_var` the same statement isn't it?

Comment: Both forms give the same output (so does `$var="$"local_var`). But I had only seen `$var=\$local_var` used before.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader They're equivalent, just different ways of suppressing the special meaning of `$` on the first parsing pass. `$var='$local_var'` or even `$var'=$local_var'` would work as well.

Comment: @Sergio how does `eval $var=\$local_var` === `foo=$local_var`

Comment: @FayVor eval is a builtin command described in `man bash`: "*The args are read and concatenated together into a  single  command. This command is then read and executed by the shell*". I'd suggest reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23117/281661